# If an API does not provide push notifications. What other methods can be used?

Tags: android, api, google-cloud-messaging

See how the Google Gmail api provides push notifications

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

Hypothetically say one wanted to use an API like this alchemy news api

http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/newsapi

and the developer wanted to send push notifications when a new article was posted under a topic.

Considering there is no push notification support for the alchemy api, what alternatives are there for push notifications?

Comment: have the app check the api periodically to see if there are new articles and then just create a custom notification using the notification manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can periodically poll your API using a Web app like Google App Engine and send client push notifications using a mechanism like Google Cloud Messaging.

Checkout https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/blob/master/GcmEndpoints/README.md

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own server which handles the updates from the site you mention and send push notifications to your users by implementing GCM in your server.